# Do I need simulink to model the risks of an option portfolio

Tags: option-pricing, risk-management, matlab, stress-testing

I wish to buy Matlab Home and learn to model the risks of a derivatives portfolio and then stress test it.

So I am guessing I will need :
Stochastic calculus
Linear algebra
Stats/Probability
Some ML algorithms?
So is it enough to purchase Matlab Home for 149$ or I need to purchase simulink also?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not an expert in this field but I set up quite some simulation studies in Matlab and I never had to use Simulink before.

Comment: Thanks. So what is purpose of simulink if matlab by itself can do everything? maybe matlab cannot implement ML agorithms?

Comment: If I may be a little cynical here, these extra cost packages are a way for Matlab to earn extra $$$ from users that are rich but lazy (or in a hurry)... Such as investment banks and hedge funds.

Comment: @Victor123 Simulink seems to be primarily targeted at controls engineers, as it allows them to "program" a control system by drawing box diagrams very similar to how the subject is taught in school. As a simple example of such a diagram, take a look at the one at the top of the wiki page for a PID Controller (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller) and think about how one might implement that in simulink.

Comment: Can confirm this answer. I believe Simulink is hardly used in finance, never heard it mentioned or seen it in vacancies.